# Can I get permission to edit on ServerFault based on my SO rep?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, edits

I just answered this question over on SF and would like to edit the question title to reflect that the OP was asking about OS X.

[OS X: setting display resolution and mirroring](https://serverfault.com/questions/39149/how-to-set-projector-machine-to-always-mirror-at-1024x768)

Would it be possible to get this permission based on my linked SO account, where I have enough points to do this?  I doubt I'm ever going to answer enough sysadmin-y questions on SF to boost my score much above what it is now.

**update:** the larger question has to do with being able to rely on my reputation from one site to edit on another site.  If the sites were totally unrelated (diesel mechanics, cooking, and gardening) I would think "no" is a reasonable answer.  For strongly related sites such as these I think the answer might veer more towards "yes."

Comment: Related questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/spelling-and-grammar-flag (lack of reputation and editing) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/rep-transfer-from-meta (reputation transfer)

Comment: Completed... sort of. Anyone can submit suggested edits now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention and we will do it.

**Everyone gets 10 moderator flags per day -- use 'em!!**

Comment: One would've thought that moderator flags were for important things, like Rich B's edit wars... not for things like a mere title edit.

Comment: they are for whatever you want to communicate to a moderator, about a post

Comment: @Jeff, I think that's a bit too much friction -- most people (myself included) think like Vinko.  Is there a problem with being able to depend on my SO reputation?

Comment: Perhaps the hint "Flag this post for serious problems" is a deterant ? Maybe a "softer" message would encourage it's use.

Comment: @Mark no, then go earn 2k rep :)

Comment: *facepalm* @ Vinko.

Comment: What was the conceptual reason behind splitting to multiple sites? Was identity and reputation sharing dangerous? I feel I should listen to a podcast, but which one?

Comment: @Jeff, will do, don't forget to upmod my brilliant insights every chance you get! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even with the related nature of SO and SF there isn't much of an overlap between experts in one and experts in the other.

Your reputation is a measure of how much the system trusts you and you have to earn that trust.

Yes, there will be a few sys admins who are good programmers and vice versa, but for the majority of us knowing a lot about programming doesn't make you qualified to answer server questions. If you can't answer questions or pose good questions yourself how can the system measure your abilities.

There will be more of an overlap between SO & SU and SF & SU, but if you are active on SU from day one (or two) then you should be able to gain enough rep to earn edit, close and even moderation privileges fairly rapidly. I've been active here on MSO since it launched and already have full edit rights. In a week or so (assuming the same level of activity) I'll have close rights. It doesn't take long.

I can see the argument for using the rep on one site to influence the rights on another, but my experience here has shown me that it's not really necessary.