# Let people without editing rep help fix answers/questions!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, moderators, flags

I've seen a few takes already on [how does flagging work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/details-about-the-flagging-mechanism) and that there's no need for a [cleanup flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/spelling-and-grammar-flag) open to more than the few moderators around.

[Jeff's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/spelling-and-grammar-flag/3082#3082) [take](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/serverfault-can-i-get-permission-to-edit-based-on-my-so-rep/4651#4651) on the issue is clear, bother moderators even for trivial things (if you don't have the rep but care enough to see it fixed), like a title edit or retagging.

Welbog's suggestion (which I intended to convey and failed miserably at it):

You have over 175 +10k-rep users on SO. Why not add a flag that is like the moderator flag but is visible to +10k users instead of just moderators? A flag for littler things like retagging, closing or cleanup. I personally would respond to such flags when I am online, especially if it contained a little blurb about the complaint. The moderator flag would remain as a method of handling bigger problems, and moderators would be able to see the +10k flags as well. Or, rather, +10k users would be able to "promote" their flags into moderator flags if they need moderator attention.

This way we won't waste manpower because people "haven't got enough rep" to help, even if they wish to (because, let's be honest, flagging a post over a title edit just isn't gonna happen ).

Comment: Leave a comment on the question. I've seen this work out very well (i.e.-a user says "Fix typo" in the comment, and I go in and fix the typo). I don't have > 10k rep, but I have at least enough to edit posts.

Comment: @Eric: A comment doesn't issue any sort of notification the way a flag does. If you don't have 2000 reputation yet and see a problem with a question or answer, you can leave a comment, but that doesn't mean anybody will see the comment.

Comment: @Welbog: The amount of traffic on this site is impressive. If you caught it early enough that somebody with > 2k rep hasn't seen it yet, chances are they will within a few minutes.

Comment: @Eric: I've seen a lot of questions that have gone for hours without much-needed edits. It's certainly true that the more interesting questions and questions with popular tags get edited quickly, but this doesn't apply to every question, and it certainly doesn't apply to answers.

Answer (score 3):

The flagging system now [explicitly allows for noting a close reason](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), and [everyone can edit](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/).

Answer (score 1):

How about doing what Jeff suggests until the moderators complain?

Answer (score -4):

Is this a Monty Python skit or a question?

Obviously, **the *real* solution is to earn enough reputation that you can edit stuff yourself**.

But if some part of a post bothers you so much that you just *have* to see it changed OMG RIGHT NOW NO MATTER WHAT, then use the moderator flag and let us know about it.

That is not the same as "flag every trivial thing in the system". Good lord, people! Use your common sense!

Comment: I respect the concept of earning enough reputation, but for some of us the amount of time we need to spend on SO/SU makes it almost impossible. Please don't see this as a complaint, however we do want to support SO/SU positively, however there are physical limitations making it hard. IE. I only get time to briefly scan SO during the day due to work, and have other community activities taking up the rest of my time. The rate at which questions are answered and time differences makes building reputation harder. IMHO.

Comment: @Jeff: You've suggested to Mark that he should flag a post to change a title. What's not trivial about that? What's so stupid about encouraging people without enough rep to contribute improving questions/answers?

Comment: @Diago, you gotta give 110%! That's what I'm saying! :)

Comment: I've been a fairly regular member for about 7 months, and I haven't quite got the reputation to edit wiki posts. Maybe once I've been a member for 2 years I'll have enough to edit other people's conventional posts.

Comment: You have over 175 +10k-rep users on SO. Why not add a flag that is like the moderator flag but is visible to +10k users instead of just moderators? A flag for littler things like retagging, closing or cleanup. I personally would respond to such flags when I am online, especially if it contained a little blurb about the complaint. The moderator flag would remain as a method of handling bigger problems, and moderators would be able to see the +10k flags as well. Or, rather, +10k users would be able to "promote" their flags into moderator flags if they need moderator attention.

Comment: @Welbog: Exactly, that's the solution to problem 2. I even propose to see if it's worth it by encouraging people to flag bad answers first and see if there are lots of 'miniflags' before commiting to a bigger change.

Comment: You only need to clear/solve problems around the reputation earning system itself and you are ready to go. Hmm, nice paradox.

Comment: I wonder if I have to formalize my suggestion as a feature request in order to get Jeff to take a look at it... Vinko Vrsalovic, will you add my suggestion to your post? Or would you prefer that I create a new feature request for it?

Comment: I tried... let's see what happens next.

Comment: voting down my posts. Harrumph. Screw you guys, I'm taking my websites and GOING HOME!

Comment: @Jeff @wood: You can just see the people who downvoted you and ban them forever!

Comment: @Jeff: That's what you get when you say these Web sites are run by **YOU**. I guess it's fair enough ;) Don't you think?!