# What are acceptable reasons for flagging as "Requires Moderator attention"?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flags

After reading [Is "Please Vote to Close" a valid use for Flag - Requires Moderation Attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10781), I feel I don't quite understand this function.

What are the guidelines for flagging a question as "Requires Moderator attention"?

Answer (score 20):

I think the determining factor is it's okay to flag for a moderator's attention if there is an issue that cannot be easily fixed in a timely fashion by the normal processes available to the community (voting, closing, comments, meta discussion, etc).

For example, if someone posted graphic adult content or blatant spam, simply closing it wouldn't really solve the problem. You need a Moderator to "fix" that problem.

Answer (score 17):

- Is it something out of the ordinary that the existing vote buttons don't convey?

This is also discussed in the comments on the [original blog announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/).

One of the more common uses is when something might represent site abuse:

- posts with illegal content
- improper activity, such as [astroturfing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/astroturfing-on-stack-overflow)
- etc

Don't forget that we also tend to look at spam/offensive votes (plus the system handles these automatically if it gathers enough votes)... so *generally* the moderator flags are for **when you need to say something additional (hence the text box)**.

Answer (score 12):

> I think the determining factor is if something has to be done that is not covered by the normally [sic] processes in place (voting, discussion, etc).

...or the flagger lacks sufficient reputation to perform that action himself.

Comment: this is also a valid use as long as it's not obsessive, but it has not historically been a problem

Comment: Or it's mod-only, like a post that needs a post notice (on sites that use those).

Answer (score 3):

[Another specific case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183):

> If you think something should be community wiki then flag it for mod attention with a comment to that effect.

Comment: But note that this is a notoriously grey area, so it would have to be a pretty obvious wiki candidate