# Option to flag code from mobile as needing formatting

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, mobile-web

Sometimes, I do some short code extracts when I'm typing an answer in the mobile site. However, getting code formatting on a mobile is HELL, as double space means full stop followed by space, which is usually helpful, but not when indenting code.

What I suggest is putting a checkbox at the bottom (only on mobile!), which says something like "code in your answer?" and then if it is checked, the question is submitted to some section of review (suggested edits, or even a new one, formatting edits?) with a note saying something like "this post was posted from the mobile site and needs formatting help". 
(Before criticism about laziness, please try ACTUALLY indenting code on a phone.)

Or, if possible, have an automatic code detector that auto-indents the code, but that would take quite a long time to implement.

Anyone with me?

Comment: That's an issue with your phone's editor, not something SO can fix.

Comment: All smartphones have that feature. I just want something to help with it.

Comment: No, not all. My iPhone 5 doesn't do this, on the full or mobile site.

Comment: Odd, it happens on an iPhone in my house and my phone (HTC 8X)

Comment: It only happens for me if I have characters before I want to indent, which seems like a use case that shouldn't be happening. If it's just an empty line (or a line with text after the cursor), I can add as many spaces as my heart desires.

Comment: It happens to me on a line with text after the cursor, but not in an empty one.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5052/flagging-a-question-for-improvement-without-voting-to-close

Comment: Downvoters, just because it got reopened doesn;t mean you should show your disagreement by downvoting the question!

Comment: That's how one shows disagreement on Meta: By downvoting.

Comment: @AlEverett I know, but the decision to reopen was not mine, I did not ask for it, I did not know until I lost rep, and now I'm getting the rep hit?

Comment: Closed questions can be downvoted too.

Comment: @AlEverett Down-votes were after re-open.

Answer (score 8):

Eh.

Asking for improvements to the mobile site is one thing, but having a queue for others to clean up your mess because you're accessing the site on an inconvenient device seems like the wrong approach.

Should there by another queue for "I'm just too lazy to format this"?

Comment: Have you tried formatting code in a mobile?

Comment: I'd prefer to think of it as _"It'll take me 5 minutes to format this now - I'll let someone else do it, and fix another post when I get back to my desktop later in only 1 minute"_

Comment: @ofstream Don't get me wrong, I know that it sucks (and have purposely avoided doing it much for just that reason), but this seems like the wrong solution.  If it were implemented, what's to stop someone who's just too lazy to do any formatting from checking that option and asking others to do their work for them?

Comment: It shouldn't be enabled on desktop, obviously.

Comment: @ofstream That doesn't mean that I can't make a userscript or play with my user agent to make it visible.  If it exists, people can abuse it.

Comment: Only lazy people would do that. Lazy people don't make userscripts or mod their user agent.

Comment: @Eric You could just put a note in the post saying "plz excuse formatting am on mobile" or similar and either someone would fix it, or you could when you got back to your desk.

Comment: @ofstream Historically, the lazy have been known to rouse themselves if a bit of initial effort will save them a lot of effort in the future.  But sure, maybe abuse wouldn't be a problem.  The shifting of responsibility from poster to others is still a problem.  Should there be a queue for posts from non-English speakers who are too lazy to translate before posting?

Comment: Review is BASED on that idea.