# Is there a manner to flag questions or answers made by non native English speakers?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, non-english-speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I think we need a flag for non-English speakers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31309/i-think-we-need-a-flag-for-non-english-speakers)

Almost all my questions or answers need a review of a native speaker. Is it possible that I flag my account as "non native speaker of English" and my Q&A goes to review automatically? It can be useful if Stack Overflow shows as well something like: "This user is not a native speaker of English. The post is pending for review". And after review this warning can change to: "English reviewed by a native speaker".

Comment: Review will happen anyway when users stumble upon your posts. No need for any extra flags or signs.

Comment: If Internet in general and SE in particular have taught me one thing, then it's that "English reviewed by a native speaker" is an utterly worthless label at best. In fact, there's a whole range of mistakes that are very typical for native speakers but are virtually unheard of among non-native ones. Such is life.

Comment: @ЯegDwight You should of given a few examples. Their not so easy to imagine if one has never seen them.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh boy, if there was ever a moment where I wanted to edit a comment....grr :p

Comment: @Bart Flag it as offensive ;)

Comment: I hope you notice that most people interested in this question are not native English speakers...

Comment: But guys, for me, when I see a Portuguese (my language) technical text wrote by a non native speaker, it's so weird, and it seems sometimes as "joke" or "troll". This is my worry.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for something like this.

You're far better off just waiting for someone who will naturally come across your question to fix it up for you. They'll understand the topic since it interests them (hence why they visited it) and are likely able to edit the question more constructively than some random person reviewing flags.

If your question isn't understandable in its current form, then a flag would be utterly useless because you'd need further discussion (in the comments) to determine exactly what you're asking about before edits could even be made. Again, it's far better to let someone that's actually interested in the topic help you with that.

There are a *lot* of flags, and a lot that are more important than fixing up the English in a post, so a flag for a reason such as this is likely to be simply dismissed as an invalid flag, like many of the "very low quality" flags that appear, or get a half-hearted edit to get rid of the flag.

Comment: If there's no need, so I must be crazy.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to flag posts written by who doesn't speak English as first language. If there is a typo that needs to be corrected, it will be corrected by who reads the post. If your post is not clear, somebody will point that out in a comment.

The fact that a post has been reviewed by a native speaker of English is irrelevant. As long as the post can be understood, there is no need for such a review.