# Should SO rep be considered in SU and SF?

Tags: discussion, reputation, linked-accounts

I have a 5k rep on SO.  I don't visit Server Fault or Super User often, so I have much less rep on those sites.

Whenever I see a question on SU or SF which does not belong or needs correction, I immediately move my mouse pointer to the question options.  But I won't see them as I don't have enough rep.

Do you feel that SO reputation should be considered in these circumstances?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)

Answer (score 14):

No, it shouldn't. Same reasons as here:
[Rep transfer from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/rep-transfer-from-meta)

Answer (score 8):

No, your reputation between the sites should not carry over. As a personal example, I have been able to accumulate just short of 13,000 reputation on StackOverflow, but I know next to nothing about the subject matter on ServerFault. I would not expect someone like myself to really know "what is going on" over at ServerFault, therefore I would not expect someone like myself being automatically grandfathered in to certain privileges because I have them on another website.

Your reputation is a big jumble of your activity, knowledge, and trust the system and community puts into you. Not all of those things carry over from site to site. Therefore your reputation should be a per-site score only.

Comment: While I agree with your details, I disagree with your opening summary "you[r] reputation between the sites should not carry over" -correct would seem to be: limited including appropriate reputation should carry over as to prove you're a human and post vote ups & make comments: while I can(finally!) post fine on StackOverflow, I just found obscure fix  http://superuser.com/questions/623505/turn-on-the-link-hover-statusbar-in-google-chrome/726721#comment-931705 which greatfully works well for me but I cant even vote it up(&it needs it) nor even comment saying it worked for me --not good.

Answer (score 4):

Associate your accounts, and you'll have 100 extra rep which is enough to vote both up and down

Answer (score 2):

No, I rock at programming, but suck at servers. Giving me SF rep based on my SO rep would be like hiring a really great plumber to perform heart-surgeries at the local St. Jude.

I'm proudly 10k+ on SO and ~150 on SF. I don't expect this ratio to change very soon either.