# Suggestion: Carry over (some) reputation between StackExchange sites

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su)
>   [Should SO rep be considered in SU and SF?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15117/should-so-rep-be-considered-in-su-and-sf)

Today I ran across another fine StackExchange site, security.stackexchange.com, that I had never visited before. The question I viewed was interesting, and the most highly voted answer was insightful; but the answer also contained a [false statement](http://xkcd.com/386/). I was, sadly, unable to comment on the answer and help improve it, because I lacked the necessary reputation on security.stackexchange.com.

This isn't the first time I've wanted to comment, but was unable. I often find myself wanting to add a small note to someone's answer, or request clarification from the author on a site I've never visited before. New StackExchange shards seem to pop up with regularity.

So my suggestion is this: Let a user's reputation on a given StackExchange site carry some (lesser) amount of weight with other **related** StackExchange sites.

It's not like my StackOverflow rep is [through the roof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (yet), but it seems that I [visit](http://stackexchange.com) [so](https://security.stackexchange.com/) [many](https://superuser.com/) [different](https://serverfault.com/) [StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) [sites](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) [just](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) [for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) [my](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) [day](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) [job](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Shouldn't my rep on StackOverflow carry some weight with SuperUser, programmers.stackexchange.com, or other related sites?

Comment: remember you can suggest edits!

Comment: Ah, good point. I never think of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have 200 rep on any SE site, you should automatically gain 100 rep on every SE site you register on, so long as you use the same OpenID (or email, if Google is your OpenID provider). This allows you to participate in basic site functions, like commenting.

Comment: Oh, no kidding. I'm still a little short of 200. Is that documented anywhere? I don't see it in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I (now) have over 200 rep on SO, but my other accounts all have less than 100.  Do I have to have over 200 rep *before* I create a new account for this to work?

Comment: @D.N. Go to your user profile on SO, click the "Accounts" tab, click "Clear all associations", log out, and then log back in.

Comment: I assume it pops up a warning for a reason.  Are you sure that's a safe thing to do?  I'd hate to permanently screw up all my accounts somehow...

Comment: @D.N. Yep, it's perfectly safe.

Comment: :O I didn't realize it would add 100 rep to each site! Seems kinda like cheating...but I won't argue.  Thanks for letting me hijack the comments :)