# Why treat existing users from the StackOverflow ecosystem as brand new when they log into sister sites?

Tags: discussion, sister-site

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should SO rep be considered in SU and SF?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15117/should-so-rep-be-considered-in-su-and-sf)

I have been a member of StackOverflow.com for a while now. Just today, I posted something on superuser.com and got the old, you can't post images unless you have 10 reputation points and you can't answer your own question unless you have 10 points.

Although it might make sense to keep certain aspects siloed, why not integrate the rest so that the user can have a unified and uniform experience?

Answer (score 11):

When you get 200 reputation on any of your Stack Exchange accounts, you'll be automatically awarded a [100 points association bonus on all your accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/162704) that will grant you all privileges up to ["edit community wiki"](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) on all sites, including [removing new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user), [participating on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta), [voting up](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) and other basic privileges.

Other than that, what you need to remember is that each Stack Exchange site has its own community, culture and, up to a point, rules. You being a Stack Overflow regular doesn't mean you know much about, for example, [Linguistics Stack Exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/?as=1).  If you are interested in the Linguistics community, you'll need to earn the not so basic privileges by actively participating and contributing to the site, same as you did with Stack Overflow.