# Can I move reputation from Stack Overflow to Server Fault? Why not?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, site-crossover, rep-transfer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site)
>   [Should SO rep be considered in SU and SF?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15117/should-so-rep-be-considered-in-su-and-sf)
>   [Rep transfer from meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/rep-transfer-from-meta)

I'm a relatively new user on all 3 sites. But already I've accumulated a ton of reputation points on Stack Overflow which I could use as bounties on Server Fault. My areas of expertise are just very lopsided towards programming, so I can help on one site but I need serious help on the other.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/rep-transfer-from-meta

Comment: Didn't realize this was such a hot topic. These reputation points are pretty useless if I can't exchange them for anything of value. I guess I'll go learn some weird programming language now so I at least have a reason to burn up SO points.

Answer (score 0):

Ask good questions and you'll almost always get answers.  Bounties, IMAO, are a crutch for people who don't want to spend the time to ask a good, answerable question.  I'd be happy if they went away entirely.

Comment: Bounties are nice when you _really_ need people to sit down for 30 minutes and try to get something to work. See the following question (which was answered very well) which cost me 250 rep for the sake of community goodness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747009/anyone-plotting-so-via-codeswarm , it resulted in a few basic (but working) examples after the bounty was offered.

Comment: Sometimes, even the best question needs to show that the person asking it is willing to compensate you in some way. This is especially true for obvious 'oh no my boss is going to kill me' questions.

Comment: You can't kick off a bounty immediately, so "my boss is going to kill me" is a bad example.

Comment: Your narrow perspective focuses on just one use case: applying bounty to convert bad question to "good" question. But you are missing another important use case: applying bounty to convert non-urgent good question to urgent good question!

Comment: In my experience, if you're *relying* on getting the right answer out of S* in a hurry, you've already lost.

Answer (score 0):

Change your name to Linus Stallman and claim to have amnesia. Ask for help from the community in restoring your memory and identity.

It could very well be that nobody viewing your questions *knows how* to answer them, I have found this to be the case numerous times on SF. Really difficult questions like LVM metadata being out of sync when using DRBD often gather dust. If you can't find it with Google, (in my experience) you can't get it at SF.

A bounty would likely end up in an answer you can't use being selected automatically after the bounty expires, if the question is already gathering dust.

Comment: Got a link to that LVM/DRBD question?  Search isn't finding it.  And yes, SF is nothing but the Sysadmin's Lazyweb.

Comment: The bounty increases the number of eyeballs on the question for sure. So the chances of some highly specialized expert seeing your "hard question" goes up just by pure statistics.

Comment: increasing eyeballs != getting good answers