# Exchange Rate between sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can I move reputation from Stack Overflow to Server Fault? Why not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29846/can-i-move-reputation-from-stack-overflow-to-server-fault-why-not)

So now that we have the [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/), should we have an exchange rate for Rep between the sites?  I'd like to transfer some Rep :)

Comment: I will trade you some rep for my 2nd round draft pick, back-up PHP developer, cash considerations and a developer to be named later.

Comment: @Michael - haha, are you sure you can make this trade, you need to watch your Rep Cap! :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree that reputation should not be freely interchangeable, for the reasons outlined by @Jon B, with one exception: Bounties.

One should be able to [start a bounty in site B with reputation earned on site A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site).

Constant participation on a site in the Stack Exchange network - any site - should buy you the right to ask questions in a field you don't know much about with that small additional edge a bounty gives you.

Comment: implementation would be a bit of a nightmare though

Comment: @Jeff yeah, that occurred to me afterwards, too... Maybe a very simplistic system (the full bounty sum must be deducted from *one* site)?

Comment: this would also be open to weird cross-site gaming issues -- like foreign currency exchange stuff. Far too problematic to ever be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Rep measures your contribution to a specific site. If you are a high rep user on one site, that doesn't mean you have a good understanding of how another site works (aside from the basic mechanics).

There is a 100 point account association bonus, however.